# How can I obtain a string of characters of the same length of another string?

Tags: python, string, replace, character

Suppose, I have a string

```
ContactMap(const core::data::structural::Structure &structure, double cutoff_distance, core::data::structural::selectors::AtomSelector_SP atoms_in_contact=nullptr)
```

I need to create a string of **`*`** (asterisks) of the same length.

I can think of the following two techniques:

1. calculate the length of the string, and use a for loop to create a string of the same length
2. take a copy of the string, and replace each character with an **`*`** (asterisk)

Do you have any other ideas?

What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: `'*' * len(mystr)`

Answer (score 2):

Luckily Python allows to multiply a string and an integer:

```
string = 'abc'
print('*' * len(string))
```

outputs

```
***
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```py
string = "ContactMap(const core::data::structural::Structure &structure, double cutoff_distance, core::data::structural::selectors::AtomSelector_SP atoms_in_contact=nullptr)"
print(string)
print("*" * (len(string)))
```

If you try it, you can see that the string and line of `*` are exactly the same length.